# Transform to output xml based on the value of an element in the input xml

Tags: xslt

I am trying to learn the basics of XSLT, but am stuck on a particular use case. What I want to achieve is to transform one xml file into another xml (I am using XSLT 2.0), but a condition is that the grouping of elements in the output xml is decided by the value of one particular element in the input xml.

I will try to exemplify my question through a made-up example.

Lets say this is an input xml:

```
<products>
<shoes>
    <shoe>
        <name>Ecco City</name>
        <category>Urban</category>
    </shoe>
    <shoe>
        <name>Timberland Forest</name>
        <category>Wildlife</category>
    </shoe>
    <shoe>
        <name>Asics Gel-Kayano</name>
        <category>Running</category>
    </shoe>
</shoes>
<clothes>
    <shorts>
        <name>North Face</name>
        <category>Wildlife</category>
    </shorts>
    <shorts>
        <name>Adidas Running Shorts</name>
        <category>Running</category>
    </shorts>
</clothes>
```

Based on the value of the category element I want to, for each product, list similar products, that is, other products having the same category in the input xml, like this:

```
<output>
    <forSale>
        <item>Asics Gel-Kayano</item>
        <similarItem>Adidas Running Shorts</similarItem>
    </forSale>       
</output>
```

Comment: Study any grouping examples in XSLT 2.0 like https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples and then give it a try and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: The output snippet you show is ambiguous - please post the complete output you expect to get from the given example input.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a grouping problem as such. If I understand correctly, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="product-by-category" match="*" use="category" />

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="*/*">
            <forSale>
                <item>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                </item>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('product-by-category', category) except .">
                    <similarItem>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                    </similarItem>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </forSale>     
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <forSale>
      <item>Ecco City</item>
   </forSale>
   <forSale>
      <item>Timberland Forest</item>
      <similarItem>North Face</similarItem>
   </forSale>
   <forSale>
      <item>Asics Gel-Kayano</item>
      <similarItem>Adidas Running Shorts</similarItem>
   </forSale>
   <forSale>
      <item>North Face</item>
      <similarItem>Timberland Forest</similarItem>
   </forSale>
   <forSale>
      <item>Adidas Running Shorts</item>
      <similarItem>Asics Gel-Kayano</similarItem>
   </forSale>
</output>
```